# How best to break shader logic down into components that can be mixed and matched

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm fairly new to shader programming and am struggling to find information on this, despite expecting it to be a somewhat obvious question.

Say I have a bunch of materials.  I want some of them to have an outline glow, some of them to show a silhouette, and others to both glow and turn into a silhouette.  From a traditional programming perspective, you'd want the outline glow logic to exist in one function, and the silhouette logic to be in another, and then be able to call one or both of them for the desired outcome.

With materials only being able to use a single shader, what is the best practice for "chaining" together multiple shaders like this?  From all my reading around, the de facto approach is to basically write a shader for each combination of functionality, which just feels like a maintenance nightmare if you have lots of different, disparate shaders that appear in different permutations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## You can do this...sort of

Here's the thing: any given object can only have 1 material<sup>1</sup> and any given Material can only have 1 shader.

So your options are:

- Multiple Materials (using shader values to tweak properties)
- Multiple Materials (using multiple different shaders)
- [*SubShader Tags*](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SL-SubShaderTags.html)

This last one is where things get interesting. SubShader tags are the closest to the Thing you are looking for. Each subshader has a set of tags associated with it. That subshader only gets applied if the Material has that same tag value.

For example, I have this shader (in a project I haven't worked on in a while):

```
Shader "Custom/Wallhack" 
{
    Properties 
    {
        _MainTex ("Base (RGB) Trans (A)", 2D) = "white" {}
        _WireColor("WireColor", Color) = (1,0,0,1)
        _Color("Color", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
        _HighlightColor("HighlightColor", Color) = (1,0,0,1)
        _HighlightSize("Highlight Size", float) = 4
    }
    SubShader 
    {
        Tags { "Queue"="Transparent" "Wallhack"="1" }
    }
    SubShader 
    {
        Tags { "Queue"="Transparent" "Wallhack"="2" }
    }
    SubShader 
    {
        Tags { "Queue"="Transparent" "Wallhack"="3" }
    }
}
```

Just assume that those subshaders have Pass entries with geom, vert, or frag methods, as well as some other tags omitted. Including all of that would make the example too long. In this case:

- `"Wallhack"="1"` is the standard render path (not visible behind walls)
- `"Wallhack"="2"` is highlight outline (for mouse-over-selections)
- `"Wallhack"="3"` is a full wireframe outline visible through other geometry

By doing nothing, the only pass that renders is the first one (the Material has the tag set to 1). But by calling [`render.material.SetOverrideTag("WallHack","3");`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Material.SetOverrideTag.html) on an object's `Renderer` component, it instead renders with the wireframe portion of the shader instead.

**Note:** I do not know what kinds of rendering overhead subshader tags caused, but I imagine that it isn't very good (breaks batching, clones the material, etc). I haven't messed with it in a while.

1 <sub>Well, sort of. Some objects have submeshes which can have their own materials, but in general: 1 mesh, 1 material.</sub>